# Is there any value in keeping more than one PostgreSQL base backup?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that was configured by someone else, there's a cron script to take a basebackup every morning, and currently we are keeping 15 days of basebackups. As I understand it, when pg_basebackup successfully completes, the database deletes WAL files that are older than the basebackup generated, which means that point in time recovery can only be achieved as of the last basebackup (unless you want to restore the database to the exact point in time of a previous basebackup, I guess).

It seems to me that this means that there's no point in keeping any basebackups older than the last successful one. Does anyone have any advice on this? The basebackups are taking up too much space on a smallish server and either I need to delete some of them or I need to increase the size of the server, and hence the cost.

Answer (score 4):

If something goes wrong with the data (let's say some sort of corruption) and it goes unnoticed for a few days or just overnight. You might end up with data loss if you only keep the last backup.  Or if the last backup was somehow bad, you'd be in trouble.

For example if a table contains records that are accessed not so frequently like once a week for reporting or once a month and someone deleted some of them on accident then you'll be short a few records and shy a few days of backup protection.

You'll probably have to look at what's in the database and decide how many you want.  Maybe just keep 7 and every week do a backup recovery to verify the last backup is usable.  And then some scripts to verify the integrity of important data and some email notifications for information about the whole shebang.

Comment: Craig is onto something; if you want to save space you could do less base backups and more wal archiving.  You may tinker with the checkpoints and even simply use the archive command for off-site archiving.  Mix in some compression and a 'not so active' database and you might be able go for quite some time.  I'd still recommend verifying it works, often.

Comment: Yes - though that is true of anything. Backups that are untested are a false sense of security. It is one of the reasons why I clean-install and recover from backups when I upgrade a machine, like a new SSD for my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a point; as Drew notes, it'll help you if you didn't notice for a while that there's undetected table corruption, accidental data deletion, etc.

Rather than keeping frequent base backups, consider using the free and open source [PgBarman](http://pgbarman.org) tool to manage [continuous archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html) for you. Set a retention period, take less frequent base backups, and use the WAL (write-ahead log) archives to "replay" database changes onto a base backup to acheive a restore from a target point-in-time.

(Disclosure: I work with the team who develop barman, though I don't work on it myself).

Also, if the base backups are on the same server as the database *you're doing it wrong*. Get them offsite, or at least on a different host (preferably attached to durable storage inside a flood-resistant fire-resistant safe).

Comment: Thanks, you'e both been very helpful. If my database server is on a rackspace cloud server, what would you recommend for the offsite backup? A separate cloud server to store the backups on, or something else? This is a setup I inherited from others so I'm learning about it as I go along. Thanks again.

Comment: @streetcornerlurker It's less vital, for sure. I'd use the smallest VM I could, preferably in another datacenter on rackspace, and just provision it with plenty of storage. Other options include using WAL-E and archiving to Amazon S3 / Glacier, using remotely located network storage attached to the master server (makes restore harder, but means no need for a second VM), etc.